# Providing templateUrl is making it impossible to get attribute values in a directive's controller

Tags: templates, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm getting some odd behaviour when using `templateUrl` in my angular directive.

Basically, when I provide the `templateUrl` I can't seem to access the evaluated attributes from the link function or the directive controller. The link function just returns the un-evaluated expression (e.g. `{{input.text}}`), and the controller gets `undefined`.

It's easier to demonstrate using a fiddle than to explain, so I've created a very simple example **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/redders6600/pjqap/3/)**. Open the console & note the output, then comment out the `templateUrl` property and re-run the fiddle to see the difference.
Note that it doesn't happen if you move the template out of the cache and into the `template` property. Can someone explain what providing the `templateUrl` changes to cause this behaviour?

For completeness here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Text1<input ng-model="input.text"/>
    <div d-nested="" d-attr2="{{input.text}}"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.input = {};
    $scope.input.text = "some string";
}

myApp.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  return $templateCache.put('/partials/rhombus.html', 
                            '<span>Just a template.</span>');

myApp.directive('dNested', function(){
    return {
        transclude: false,
        //Comment out the below line to observe the difference.
        templateUrl: '/partials/rhombus.html',
        replace: false,
        controller: function($attrs, $scope){
            this.logAttr = function(){
                console.log("from controller: " + $attrs.dAttr2);
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
            attrs.$observe('dAttr2', function(val){
                console.log("from link function: " + val);
                ctrl.logAttr();               
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Update**

After a helpful answer from Martin below, I see that it's working now, but not when directives are nested (i.e. one is transcluded inside another). See the [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/redders6600/pjqap/6/). You will still notice commenting out the template url will result in the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be a bug in the Angular version you're using (the fiddle uses 1.0.1). It works correctly if you upgrade to 1.0.5 or newer.

Comment: Hmm, thanks I will try upgrading -- I'm using 1.0.7 locally at the moment though and am still seeing similar. I'll have a look shortly.

Comment: So having updated the version, it's fixed with the original problem (upvoted this answer), however, I still have the problem when two directives are nested. See the updated fiddle that I will link into my original question.

Comment: Hm. Looks like a bug to me. It works as expected if `template` is used, but not if `templateUrl` is used.